# gradle earlib not pulling transitive libraries

Tags: gradle, plugins, ear, transitive-dependency

I got gradle 3.5.1 and using ear plugin. The documentation says that deploy configuration is not transitive but earlib actually is (https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/ear_plugin.html). My configuration is a below

```
dependencies {
    earlib(
            "org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.8"
    )
}
```

It was supposed to get a few other transitive libraries but here is all I get when I run gradle dependencies

```
earlib - Classpath for module dependencies.
\--- org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.8
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are doing nothing wrong. Your module dependency [`org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.8`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.2.8) simply does not define any (mandatory) transitive dependency, since every *compile* or *provided* dependency is marked as **optional**.

According to the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html),

> If a user wants to use functionality related to an optional dependency, they will have to redeclare that optional dependency in their own project.

Comment: Thank you, that is correct. I am converting from a ivy project and ivy at least in my config pulls down even the optional dependencies. So that was quite confusing. And the last but not least, I should not post questions on Friday afternoon, rather wait for Monday morning and have fresh eyes :)